# Por que curl no extrae datos php

Tags: php, curl

Buenas tengo una duda porque curl no extrae los datos de esta url que parte del código esta malo o que le falta para funcionar .

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.youtube6download.top/api/?format=JSON&id=i62Zjga8JOM';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //visualizar ñ y acentos.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); //(aceptación de codificación gzip)   
$response = curl_exec($ch); //almacena el response de la pagina.

curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
?>
```

Espero su ayuda Gracias.

Comment: A mi si me funciona.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Que raro por que en localhots wampserver no refleja ningún resultado